# C++ delete pointer with valid address

Tags: c++, memory-management, fork, shared-ptr, poco

I am using Poco C++ library and cause strange problem.
Poco using own shared pointer class `SharedPtr` for internal pointer operations. At my case static object `Poco::SSLManager` has `SharedPtr` members of certificate Handlers objects. When program run ends, static object is deleted and I catch segmentation fault.
Uses GDB debugger i see core dump and don't understand problem. Seg fault is occurred when deleting `SharedPtr` object (simple operation: `delete pObj`), but object has valid address, such as - `0x8fcbed8`.

Why delete pointer with valid address can cause segmentation fault?
It's may be because object create in fork copy of application and destroy in main?

Comment: Before deleting object pointer checked for null pointer and after delete operation is set to null.

Comment: SharedPtr usually has `ptr->Release()` function. Check it out

Comment: @Reddy: Don't check for `null` before calling `delete`, because it's defined to do nothing on `null` pointers.

Comment: 2 Gasim, year ptr is checked before release called and set to null after.

Answer (score 11):

A valid address is just an accessible address. That doesn't mean that it's right for delete. You can *only* `delete` what you got back from `new`. If you didn't `new` it, you can't `delete` it. Deleting a static or automatic object is undefined behaviour- as well as one you might obtain from any other source apart from `new`.

Comment: Even furthermore, you should never delete anything that comes out of a smart pointer. Smart pointers are called "smart" because they take care of the deletion themselves.

Comment: New is did, of course. But new doing in fork process, and object stores in static object (that create from shared library - so) that destroy in parent process. Me seems it's may be a conflict.

Comment: You absolutely definitely cannot delete across *processes*.

Answer (score 0):

You speak about using a `shared pointer`. If that delete is the last delete on the pObj, it might be that it's the last time that the object is being deleted.. and so the object that the shared pointer points to will finally be destroyed. In that case the `destructor` of pObj is called and maybe you get the Seg Fault from there.

On the other hand depending on which implementation of shared pointer the Poco lib uses, it might be that you are misusing the shared pointer by calling delete on it.

Comment: Poco SharedPtr is look like smart ptr and use internal atomic counter. And i also checked destructor of my problem object (InvalidCertificateHandler). It's simple object, no parents and has only 1 bool variable. In destructor i see some calls of static object SSLManager methods, but after comment it application behaviour is not change.

Comment: I think you're using the shared ptr wrong but it's hard to guess. Please edit your post and add some of your code like the line(s) where you construct and manipulate the [Shared Ptr](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.RC.html#13607)

Answer (score 0):

as the other have said, it's not because your pointer looks "good" like 0x8fcbed8 that it's a correct pointer.

In fact, if you use "delete", the pointer will keeps its value. But you should not use it any more. (It's a good practice to set it to NULL just after a delete so it appears "empty" with a debugger.)

There is a tool that could help you to find what is wrong if you are developping with linux. It's **valgrind** :

```
valgrind  your_program  [args]
```

(just add "valgrind" in front of the command you usually launch. Install valgrind if not already here, must have a packet for it on your distro since it is a widely used tool.)

Then valgrind will inspect your program while it run (slowing it a bit) and report you immediatly as soon as you delete something you should not. (and a lot of other errors)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult problem and i don't understand problem full, but i try to explain it and my resolution.
Problem is platform-specific and occurres only on Gentoo linux with gcc 4.5.5 compiler with Poco Libraries.

I have daemon that use modules (plugins) for processing different requests. Modules and daemon use one static library that use poco library. In static library have code to create SSL connections and as result creates SSL manager. Static library is linked to module and to deamon.

And after end's of working deamon i have segmentation fault that describes in my question. I change static library to shared library and problem is gone, no seg faults. All works fine.

Really, i don't understant it, but seems it's gcc compiler bug on gentoo. On others linux with other gcc all works good with static library.

Comment: Gentoo linux with gcc 4.5.5 - mistake 4.4.5 version